# SHDocVw::IShellWindowsPtr, Windows 8.1 and Modern(Metro) IE11

Tags: windows, winapi, bho, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I have an application that enumerates Internet Explorer instances on a machine. It uses an instance of SHDocVw::ShellWindows (and a SHDocVw::IShellWindowsPtr pointer) to get the count of running IE windows. The application has been running as expected so far.

Testing on Window 8.1 preview and IE11 what I discovered was that the application was able to successfully enumerating instances of IE that were running in desktop mode. But, it was not able to “see” any Metro IE11 instances. Has anyone come across similar behavior? Is this intended behavior for IE11 or is a bug (seeing that it works in desktop IE11)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: Feature, not a bug.  Metro apps run in a strong sandbox that prevents desktop apps from interacting with them.  Being able to obtain an IShellWindows interface pointer would be pointless, there isn't anything you can do with it.

Comment: Hans is correct, and his comment should be promoted to "Answer."

Comment: @Hans, I agree with the sandbox argument. But this mechanism has been working fine on Windows 8 with Metro IE. Maybe its a bug in Windows 8 then?

Comment: Sound remote, but that would be an 8.0 bug, fixed in 8.1